# NavigationBar Title Did Not Inline When Scrolling

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-scrollview

I am very new to Swift and SwiftUI. I am trying to create the Contacts View of Apple's Phone app. I am using Xcode 14.3.1. My aim is to make navigation title get inline mode when scrolling. But the search bar and the navigation title stay still all the time.

```
//
import SwiftUI

struct ContactsView: View {
    @State var personname: String = ""
    @StateObject var personViewModel = PersonViewModel()
    let headers: [Character] = [ "A", "B", "C", "Ç", "D", "E", "F", "G", "Ğ", "H", "I", "İ", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "Ö", "P", "R", "S", "Ş", "T", "U", "Ü", "V", "Y", "Z"
]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
                ZStack{
                    VStack {
                        TextField("Search", text: $personname)
                            .padding()
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                            .frame(maxHeight: 50)
                            .background(Color("SearchColor"))
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                            .padding(.horizontal)
                        
                        List(){
                            UserProfileView()
                            ForEach(headers, id: \.self) { header in
                                Section{
                                    ForEach(personViewModel.persons.filter { $0.getfullname().hasPrefix(String(header)) }, id: \.id) { person in
                                        EachPersonView(PersonModel: person)
                                    }
                                }header: {
                                    Text(String(header))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                    
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                            Button{
                                print("Save tapped")
                            }label: {
                                Label("SAVE", systemImage: "plus")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Contacts")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)
                .listStyle(.inset)
        }
    }
}

struct UserProfileView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center){
            Image(systemName: "hourglass")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                .clipShape(Circle())
            
            VStack{
                Text("Person Name")
                    .bold()
                Text("My Card")
                    .offset(x: -18 , y: 0)
            }
        
        }
    }
}

struct ContactsView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContactsView()
        
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct PhoneAppApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationView{
                ContactsView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Normal view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8n6yE.png)
[Scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdm7M.png)

I used `.navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.automatic)` but apparently it did not work.
I thought maybe it caused by the absence of ScrollView so I add it before List but again it did not work and my List elements disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It's the [`VStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/vstack). Wrapping a scrolling container(`List`, `ScrollView`) inside a `VStack` renders the content as static relative to the `VStack`'s parent. You should make your search bar a [`Section`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/section) header and remove the enclosing `VStack`. Also the `ZStack` isn't contributing to anything in the view so you can remove it as well.

Now if you want the search bar to collapse into the navigation bar, you should use [`.searchable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/searchable(text:placement:prompt:)-18a8f) instead of writing a custom search bar.

**Note:** [`List`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list) does not need to be wrapped inside a `ScrollView` as the scrolling feature is already built into it.

Comment: Yess it worked. Thank you so much.